# how to prevent screen record in ios11

Tags: ios, screen, ios11, replaykit

To some reasons, our APP dont't want people record screen, but in ios11 a new feature can let user record there iphone screen, so is there an API or notification indicate me user is recording now
thank u very much

Comment: You can't completely prevent this. Even if Apple allowed disabling recording, jailbroken phones could probably get around it, and at the end of the day, recording the screen with a camera is always possible.

Comment: I do not consider jailbreak now, do you know ios11 have such an API?

Comment: No. It's been a long time since I've dealt with Apple.

Answer (score 7):

You can detect if the screen is being recorded with:

```swift
UIScreen.main.isCaptured
// True if this screen is being captured (e.g. recorded, AirPlayed, mirrored, etc.)
```

You can't prevent it using project settings, but you could use a modal or something to request the user to disable it. Not sure how that might workout with your AppStore submission.

Comment: This is not only screen capture but also mirroring with airplay. So not the exact solution.

Comment: I know, that's why I added a comment to reflect it

Comment: It's worth noting that I have seen this value return an incorrect result multiple times in testing. Frequently, we encounter a bug where the we *are* using screen recording but isCaptured returns false.

Comment: how can i detect for below ios 11??

Comment: @WongSam if this is the correct answer that solves your problem, don't forget to accept it (green tick is) ;)

Comment: if UIScreen.main.isCaptured is true, then How to Stop that record? I have start screen record, by pressing RECORD button from CONTROL CENTER, then immediately, if I open my app, then I have to STOP that record programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kvo observe `UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification` in iOS 11 like this

```
NSOperationQueue *mainQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification object:nil queue:mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) { 
 //code you want execute
}];
```

Comment: That is not KVO.

Comment: allenh, You don't need or want KVO. Notification observer is correct.