# How to understand if device screen is being recorded in IOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I have an application that it has copyrighted content. I don't want users to record it. If they start recording screen I want my app to catch this. What is the function to catch if the screen is being recorded?

I don't want to prevent, I want to understand and catch it.

Note: Some answers indicate solutions including AirPlay and Mirroring. What I want is to only catch screen recording either started before or during app. I want to allow users to use AirPlay and Mirroring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to prevent screen record in ios11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45401959/how-to-prevent-screen-record-in-ios11)

Answer (score 5):

**SWIFT 5.0**

To prevent screen recording I created a separate class `ScreenRecordingProtoector`

witch looks like that:

```
final class ScreenRecordingProtoector {

private var window: UIWindow? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window
    }
    return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window
}

func startPreventing() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preventScreenShoot), name: UIScreen.capturedDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc private func preventScreenShoot() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if UIScreen.main.isCaptured {
            window?.isHidden = true
        } else {
            window?.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Deinit
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
}
```

then simply I create a variable in AppDelegate above `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `let screenRecordingProtoector = ScreenRecordingProtoector()` and then I call inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `screenRecordingProtoector.startPreventing()`

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
private let preventService = PreventCapturingService()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    preventService.startPreventScreenRecording()

    return true
}
}
```

It works fine for me in Swift 5.0

Comment: `UIScreen.main.isCaptured` is available from iOS 11.0+, so you should change the availability check in `preventScreenShoot()`

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the screen is being recorded with this

```
UIScreen.main.isCaptured
```

Comment: This is not only screen capture but also mirroring with airplay. So not the exact solution.

Comment: Please go through this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen

Comment: I did. "When the value of this property is true, the contents of this screen are actively being recorded, mirrored, or sent over AirPlay."

Answer (score 1):

You can also detect if user has taken screenshot by listening to `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`.

You can use that in below way-

```
let main = OperationQueue.main
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot, 
    object: nil, 
    queue: mainQueue, 
    using: { notification in
        // Warn user
})
```

And

```
UIScreen.main.isCaptured
```

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2921651-iscaptured) can also be used to detect recording. I haven't used this but mostly you will have to do KVO for this.

Comment: I don't want to detect screenshot. Only want to detect recording of screen. Not also airplay or mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

Check the screen is being recorded (for Objective C)

Put the below code on your app delegate and did finish launching and did become active.

BOOL isCaptured = [[UIScreen mainScreen]isCaptured];

Answer (score 0):

Use UIScreen.main.isCaptured to get current status. Than, you need to listen to new notification UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification. When recording status will change, you need to do some action (for example stop playback ..etc.). Remember this is iOS11+ only.

Code fragments:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                    selector:@selector(capturedChange)
   name:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}


- (void)capturedChange {
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    NSLog(@"Recording Status: %s", [UIScreen mainScreen].isCaptured ? "true" : "false");
        //do something
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

isCaptured will be true if the screen is being recorded, mirrored or sent over AirPlay.

I added a check to see if mirroring is the case; if not, I show an alert. Solved my issue for the time being. This is not a perfect solution and doesn't solve all the problems, but just one extra step towards it

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(handleScreenCaptureChange)
   name:UIScreenCapturedDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)handleScreenCaptureChange
{
    UIScreen *aScreen;
    BOOL isMainScreenMirrored = NO;
    NSArray *screens = [UIScreen screens];
    for (aScreen in screens)
    {
        if ([aScreen respondsToSelector:@selector(mirroredScreen)]
            && [aScreen mirroredScreen] == [UIScreen mainScreen])
        {
            // The main screen is being mirrored.
            isMainScreenMirrored = YES;
        }
    }

    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        BOOL isCaptured = [[UIScreen mainScreen] isCaptured];
        if (isCaptured && !isMainScreenMirrored) {

            //Display Alert : "Please turn off screen recording and play again."

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if user start screen recording before open the app, then open the app ? Because isCapture will only trigger when user start the screen recording when app is in open state.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the AirPlay and Mirroring you can take a look at the length of the `UIScreen.Screens` and check whether there is more than one screen, in case of airplay there will be 2 screens.

So for example when the airplay is switched on, the capturedDidChangeNotification will be raised and there you can observe, if `UIScreen.MainScreen.Captured == true` and also if `UIScreen.Screens.Lenght > 1` then it's definitely airplay or mirror.